# Separating vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector

I'm writing a function that will separate a vector of objects into two vectors depending on the value of one of their objects.  I want it then to return whichever of the vectors.

This is the code I have so far

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> OrderBook::get_aggregated_order_book(SellBuyType which_side) const
{
    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> ret;

    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::const_iterator i = v_OrderInfo.begin();
        for (; i != v_OrderInfo.end(); ++i)
            ((*i).get_SB_type()==BUY ? v_BuyOrders : v_SellOrders).push_back((*i));

    if(which_side==SELL){
        ret = v_SellOrders;
    }
    else{
        ret = v_BuyOrders;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm getting the following error:

> [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::vector::push_back(const AggregatedQuoteType&) const'

Comment: what's the problem/question?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm getting this error
[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType>::push_back(const AggregatedQuoteType&) const'

Comment: please put the information in the question, not in the comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have marked your function `get_aggregated_order_book` as `const`.

```
OrderBook::get_aggregated_order_book(SellBuyType which_side) const
                                                             ^^^^^
                                                             Here!
```

The `const` keyword in C++ implies that you will not be making changes to any members in your class, which I presume `v_BuyOrders` and `v_SellOrders` are.

If you're modifying the members of your `OrderBook` class, you need to make the method non-const.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that as `v_BuyOrders` and `v_SellOrders` seem to be class members then they're going to get **appended** to every time this call is made. - and this is possibly a bad design decision, as each order will be duplicated within the class.

Comment: @Roddy - Good spot, that was worth mentioning!

Comment: Yes, they are class members.  How could I fix that problem @Roddy ?  I originally wanted to keep the function as a const but it's working now without it.  Thanks KarlNicoll for that.

Comment: @RuthO'Brien - You simply need to do `v_BuyOrders.clear()` and/or `v_SellOrders.clear()` before you start adding anything to them.

Comment: @RuthO'Brien Do you need to have v_BuyOrders/v_SellOrders as class members? You already have v_OrderInfo - and so you have the problem of always worrying about if the vectors are kept in sync. Maybe just make the vector local to you function?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the v_BuyOrders and v_SellOrders populated at all or just return whatever matches which_side? If the latter, how about just applying a copy_if operation and return the result?

```
std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> ret;
std::copy_if(v_OrderInfo.cbegin(), v_OrderInfo.cend(), std::back_inserter(ret),
    [=](const AggregatedQuoteType &at) { return at.get_SB_type() == which_side) };
return ret;
```

EDIT: not using lambda/C++11,

```
struct pred {
    SellBuyType type;
    pred(SellBuyType t) : type(t) {}
    bool operator()(const AggregatedQuoteType &at) {
       return at.get_SB_type() != type; // Copies the elements for which this returns false
    }
};

std::remove_copy_if(v_OrderInfo.cbegin(), v_OrderInfo.cend(), std::back_inserter(ret), pred(which_side));
```

Do note however that remove_if/remove_copy_if doesn't actually remove anything, just shifts the "removed" elements to the back of the vector. If you want to remove the elements as well use vector::erase on the return value of remove_copy_if.

Comment: Thanks, but my compiler doesn't support C++11 :(

Comment: I'm trying to use the remove_copy_if

 `std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> ret;
 
 AggregatedQuoteType at;
 
 std::remove_copy_if (v_OrderInfo.begin(),v_OrderInfo.end(),ret.begin(), at.get_SB_type() == which_side);
 
 return ret;`

Was wondering is you @imbtfab could give me a tip for the pred part?

Comment: @RuthO'Brien - I would create a separate question for this, as it's unlikely to get noticed nor answered if it's a comment :-)